# I would like to make the clock appear two times on the statusbar, for the iPod Touch. How do I do so?

Tags: ios, statusbar, clock, ipod-touch

I`ve been working on a tweak lately and I want to make a tweak where the clock appears two times on two different places on the status bar on my iPod Touch. I was wondering if someone could give me a short tutorial on how this is possible and how to write Objective-C that modifies something on the iPod Touch IOS?

Take in consideration that I am still an newbie when it comes to Objective-C Programming.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can "modify" existing UI elements, that is, you can subclass existing elements to modify them on "your" own app, but you can't change the default ones, like the status bar that is displayed across all applications. (Unless you jailbreak your device and make use of undocumented APIs if there are any for this purpose but for someone just starting, that would a humongous amount of work.

Comment: I dont like it when you make such an awful statment from ehat you think, I now it's possible and. It's very easy to do, but I am not smart enough. MobileSubstrate is the one that gives me this possibility to such things.

Comment: If you read carefully, you'll see that what I wrote is right - Cydia means it will require your device to be jailbroken. It does NOT work on non-jailbroken devices.